# Combine 2 or more pandas dataframes on date index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, combinations

I need to combine multiple dataframes on a common dates column. All dates are the same across all dataframes and I would like to preserve all data. The only column that will be affected is the dates column which will basically be replaced by a single dates column.

table 1:
Date | Price

table 2:
Date | Price

table 3:
index | Date | Price

table 4:
index | Date | Price

Comment: `table1.merge(table2, on='Date').merge(table3, on='Date').merge(table4, on='Date')`

Comment: please check joining.

Comment: Thanks, table merge worked fine. Haven't tested joining yet.